# how to php mysql draw a tree structure

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, mysql

I have the below MySQL records, so need to draw a tree structure in PHP by using the below MySQL data, here NULL value represents the primary parent node,

> `+----------------+----------------+
>   | id             | parent_id      |
>   +----------------+----------------+
>   | 1              |            NULL|
>   | 2              |            1   |
>   | 3              |            1   |
>   | 4              |            2   |
>   | 5              |            3   |
>   | 6              |            2   |
>   +----------------+----------------+`

the output should be a below format

> ```
>              1
>            /   \ 
>          2      3
>         / \    /
>        4   6  5
> ```

please help me.

try to https://www.daniweb.com/programming/web-development/threads/231905/binary-tree-using-php-mysql#post1027437

not working

Comment: You might have to look in JavaScript I don't think drawing a tree is possible using PHP.

Comment: use html , javascript and css to draw

Comment: Try with : [phpflow tutorial](https://www.phpflow.com/php/how-to-create-dynamic-tree-view-menu/)

Comment: do you want to draw the tree or create the tree structure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
function get_path($category_id) 
{
    // look up the parent of this node
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT c1.parent_id,c2.category_name AS     parent_name FROM category AS c1
LEFT JOIN category AS c2 ON c1.parent_id=c2.category_id 
WHERE c1.category_id='$category_id' ");
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);

   // save the path in this array
    $path = array();

    //continue if this node is not the root node
    if ($row['parent_id']!=NULL) 
    {
        // the last part of the path to node

        end($path);
        $last_key = key($path);
        $key = $last_key==0 ? 0 : $last_key+1;

        $path[$key]['category_id'] = $row['parent_id'];
        $path[$key]['category_name'] = $row['parent_name'];

        $path = array_merge(get_path($row['parent_id']), $path);
    }

   return $path;
}
?>
```

> To print the path, just do the following:

```
<?php
for ($i=count($path)-1;$i==0;$i--)
{
     echo $path[$i]['category_name']. '>';
}
?>
```

> You have seen how to find the path from a leaf (node with no children) to the root node. Let's now see how to go down through the hierarchy -- i.e. start from the root element and display all nodes according to their hierarchical relations:

```
<?php
function display_children($category_id, $level) 
{
    // retrieve all children
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM category WHERE     parent_id='$category_id'");

    // display each child
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) 
    {
        // indent and display the title of this child
       // if you want to save the hierarchy, replace the following line with     your code
        echo str_repeat('  ',$level) . $row['category_name'] . "<br/>";

       // call this function again to display this child's children
       display_children($row['category_id'], $level+1);
    }
}
?>
```

> http://www.phpbuilder.com/articles/databases/mysql/handling-hierarchical-data-in-mysql-and-php.html

Comment: Stumbled upon this post via search engine. The link in this answer is dead. Here's the correct link: https://phpbuilder.com/handling-hierarchical-data-in-mysql-and-php/

Answer (score 1):

You should probably try something like

```html
  1
  |->2
  |  |->4
  |  |->6
  |
  |->3
     |->5
```

Which would be easier to implement than the traditional binary graph. And will scale easily both horizontally and vertically without any UI issues.

Given a large data set, the top-bottom graph would need you to make more calculations for getting the distance between each node based on the number of child nodes they have.
Also you may need to make additional calculations to center them appropriately.